# Refresh Control UI Fails (SWIFT)

Tags: swift, user-interface, io, tableview

I have an little problem with **refresh control**. All looks good but when I navigate to another view controller and then come back, I got the following gray space:

[image]

My code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "add_employee.png"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "showEmployeeRegisterView")
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "sync.png"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "syncData")

    self.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    self.refreshControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    self.refreshControl.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    self.refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "ACTUALIZAR", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()])
    self.refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: "loadData", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

    self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    self.searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    self.searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Buscar..."
    self.searchController.searchBar.translucent = false

    let nib = UINib(nibName: "CustomTableCell", bundle: nil)

    self.tblEmployee.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    self.tblEmployee.dataSource = self
    self.tblEmployee.addSubview(refreshControl)
    self.tblEmployee.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

    self.definesPresentationContext = true
}
```

The correct UI:

[image]

So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you should move all that code to viewDidAppear so you can be sure the subviews are being added appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for response. I will try but i want to know why it failed by this way...